# Web service SocketTimeOutException causes database inconsistency

Tags: android, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2, http-post, httpclient

I want to overcome the following scenario when calling a Rails Web service from Android device with the help of Apache HTTP Client library

Scenario :

Client (Android) : Initiates HTTP POST request (Using Apache HTTP Client, JSON as exchange format) to inserts few records into the server database (MySQL).

Server (Web service in Rails) : Process the request and inserts records into the database successfully BUT at the same moment time out `(SocketTimeOutException)` occurs at the client side.

Client (Android) : On time out, retries to execute the same HTTP POST request and once again the same records get's inserted into the database and Database INCONSISTENCY occurs.

Can any one please help me to overcome this situation.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

My current scenario:

1) User tries to register using the Android app by filling and submitting data. So basically POST service contains all the required user into which is sent to the server (Rails and MySql)

2) POST request is processed by server and this process is basically responsible for inserting records into the database and providing response to client with the USER_ID for which data is inserted.

3) BOOM!! The data is inserted in the MySql database but for some reason there is `SocketTimeOutException` on the Android side and because of which there is no USER_ID on Android side and user tries to register again........ Data base inconsistency and I am SAD :(

NOTE : Occurrence of step 3) is very rare.. BUT it is frequent when server is too busy or is having some processing load on it..

Comment: I think **session based web service** is what you needed.. So session expired only when your server is completed successfully..

Comment: Can you provide some more information on creating and maintaining session based web services.. and how it will help me to overcome the problem?

Comment: You could try to increase the timeout, but this is not the ultimate solution, as the connection can still fail for any reason including timeout.

Comment: @MisterSmith Currently the timeout is set to 10sec which I think is fine.. But if the time out is increased, client (Android) will have to wait for longer duration... so again that is a problem.

Comment: No, the time out is the max time you'd have to wait for the server response in the connection call. If you set it to 60 seconds it does not mean every connection will take 60 s. But you are right, this is just kicking the can.

Comment: Can any one please help to overcome this situation please..?? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case you describe above I would suggest you add a session cookie to the proceedings. When the user posts the data you check if there is already a USER_ID for that session, if it is you return it, if not you do the database insert. So even if the initial insert happens, followed by a timeout before the user gets the response, you will be able to serve the response when the user retries the registration. Without getting your DB trashed.

You can also do a lookup in the database for an identical (or otherwise unique) record (created very recently) and return that USER_ID on the second request. This will depend on what data the user sends in. But if it's a registration and you get two posts with the same email in short succession it's a safe bet that it's from the same user ...

**Before the edit:**

Since you are using Rails you could simply leverage the [create_or_update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create_or_update) method to create the records. Basically you check if the records already exist and then update them instead of blindly inserting new ones.

This is a problem you would probably have to handle anyway since two clients could potentially post identical information at the same time even if you didn't have the problem with reposts.

If you want a more detailed description of how this works you'll have to provide more information about what the post contains. The keys and unique fields are interesting in this case as are any information about if the records are bound to a specific user etc...

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question can you please check and let me know please.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 30000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 30000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity((JSONRequest));
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            strResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

set the timeout according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**#rule** always allow php and mysql scripts to timeout before your clients (Android or any other). You can ensure this easily by appropriately setting the timeouts on all the endpoints of your system.

Specifically for your scenario, you can add a boolean to your users table and name it ***`verified`***.

1. When the user registers, verified is unset (***`verified=false`***) by default.
2. When the user logins for the first time, verified is set (***`verified=true`***).
3. When a user registers and the `username` specified already exists, allow registration **if *verified==false* else** do not allow registration.
4. (**cost**) When a user registers, he should login. It is preferable to remove the registration page and show the user a visual indicator that registration is done and now we are logging you in. I usually do this by showing upon registration a progress dialog saying "Registering..." then going to the login page and showing the user a progress dialog saying "Logging in...".

This should ensure that the problem does not occur anymore. If an error (timeout) occurs on the login screen, the user should stay on that screen so that he can retry. This is really a normal flow on android (Intent).

---

- You can of course force the login to be silent on the registration page and keep retrying until it works.
- You can also remove the extra login step and just verify the user upon the first transaction, but that would cost alot (You will have to check on each request)